# Reading Metrics from StackDriver API (Google cloud)

Tags: google-compute-engine, stackdriver

I would like read the below metric from compute engine.For that I am planning to use the StackDriver Monitoring APIs.After reading the doc,i came to know that
OATH 2.0 Authorization is required before making the https request to the API.

I would like to do it programatically in python,can any one let me know how to
get the authorize to oath 2.0 and get the access token for making request.

Ex:
instance/disk/read_bytes_count
instance/disk/write_bytes_count

Answer (score 0):

There are OAuth2 client libraries available for Python (for example [this one](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth)). However, you might find it easier to use a client library specifically for the Stackdriver Monitoring API, e.g., https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-cloud-monitoring.